# Programatically connect and disconnect USB devices to Guest in VMware Workstation

Tags: usb, script, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I am using a VMWare Workstation VM using Vmware-KVM and I would like to programatically connect and disconnect USB devices connected to the host to my guest operating system, and vice versa. Basically the same way I would do it in the VMWare Workstation UI by selecting "Disconnect from Host", but I do not want to show the Workstation UI, but rather hide it from the user. Instead, I would like to run a program or script from inside the Guest VM (or alternatively from the host) that allows me to connect or disconnect any USB device connected to the host.

Is there any tool or API to achieve this? I know that I can edit the VMX file to influence the connection behaviour at startup, but I would like to perfrom this at runtime using a script, tool, program or whatever it takes to make this work.

Any suggestions are welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be if you had one particular USB controller card that you could blacklist from the host, and passthrough to the guest.